# Type of datastructure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have multiple questions which contains sub questions. I would like to store in a data structure so that I can choose sub question when user selects the first question. Also, some sub questions uses general questions within that category. Initially I thought about using multidimensional array but then I realized it will take quite a long time to search through the array.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you

This is my solution so far.

```
//Key is the question and value(object) contains all the value related to the question
categoryToSubquestions[2] = {"What type of countertop?":{
                                "stone_slab_countertops": "Stone slab countertops",
                                "granite_countertops" : "Granite countertops",
                                "marble_countertops" : "Marble countertops",
                                "quartz_countertops" : "Quartz countertops",
                                "slate_countertops" : "Slate countertops",
                                "solid_surface_countertops" : "Solid Surface countertops",
                                "concrete_countertops" : "Concrete countertops",
                                "corian_countertops" : "Corian countertops",
                                "formica_countertops" : "Formica countertops",
                                "stainless_countertops" : "Stainless countertops",
                                "wood_or_butcher_block_countertops" : "Wood or Butcher block countertops",
                                "laminate_countertops" : "Laminate countertops",
                                "selectKey":"MappedCategory"

                            },
                             "What best describes your countertop project?":{
                                "install_or_replace": "Install or Replace",
                                "repair"        : "Repair",
                                "selectKey":"describe_countertop_project"
                            },
                             "generalQuestions2": "4"
                            };
//This is general question that other categories might use...It is being used in the above category
generalQuestion[4] = {"Is this project part of a larger remodel?":{
                            "true" : "Yes",
                            "false": "No",
                            "selectKey":"part_of_larger_remodel"
                        }
                    };
//THIS IS categoryToSuquestion index to value assosciation...(JUST TO KEEP TRACK)
var keyValue = new Array(
/*0*/           "cabinets_reface",
/*1*/           "cabinets_refinish",
/*2*/           "cabinets_countertop_install");
```

I have 70 of this right now and I am little worried if it will slow down once I keep adding more questions?

Comment: Sounds like a tree to me.

Comment: It may help to provide example(s) of your data structure. I'm not sure what you mean by "some sub questions uses general questions within that category".

Comment: Is this all happening on the client side (javascript) or are you doing any of this on the server side from a database?

Comment: Try to use a map `{ 'question' : { 'Question' : 'Question here', 'subquestions' : { ... } } }`

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a data structure like this.
Don't forget that you can access it like a Hashtable/Dictionary on its properties.

```js
var questions_data_structure = {
    "Q1": {
        "question_text": "Parent Question #1?",
        "sub_questions": ["SubQues1", "SubQues3"]
    },
    "SubQues1": {
        "question_text": "Sub Question 1?",
        "parent_question": "Q1"
    },
    "SubQues3": {
        "question_text": "Sub Question 3?",
        "parent_question": "Q1"
    },
    "Ques8": {
        "question_text": "Regular question without children questions?"
    }
}

q = questions_data_structure["Q1"];
alert(q.question_text);

if (q.sub_questions && q.sub_questions.length > 0) {
    alert("I have child questions");

    var i = 0, len = q.sub_questions.length, childQuestionObj;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        childQuestionObj = questions_data_structure[q.sub_questions[i]];
        alert(childQuestionObj.question_text);
    }
}
else {
    alert("I DON'T have child questions");
}
```

So if you tie your data structure's **KEY** values to your HTML Control IDs, you can do something like this.

```js
// include jQuery library
$.each(questions_data_structure, function(question_id, value) {
    if (value.sub_questions && value.sub_questions.length > 0) {
        $('#' + question_id).click( function(e) {
            /* Show or hide your child question controls */
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used the same structure but I was wondering if it will slow the site significantly. Currently I have 70 question and there are more coming in.

Comment: DOM insertion is very fast (takes like 0.5 seconds at most to insert 10,000 DIVs on an iPhone). So don't worry about it. It all depends on your algorithm for processing your data structure. I have written much more complex data structures with nested child nodes and nearly 200 or more nodes, and haven't run into performance problem.